# Convert json timestamp with php

Tags: php, json

I have a string that contains a "json timestamp" (I guess its called so, because of this question: [The "right" JSON date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format))

```
2015-08-11T09:19:25Z
```

Now I want to convert this string with php into something like this:

```
09:19 11.08.2015
```

I tried the date function, but it did not work.

Comment: have you seen in the other question ? > "There is no date format in JSON"

Comment: Yea but also "You should use the format emitted by Date's toJSON method" and because of the "toJSON" I thought  its a json timestamp

Comment: json has no "date" type, no time type. it has arrays, objects, integers, and strings, basically. your date is just a string. RTFM: http://php.net/date `date()` is for taking a unix timestamp and converting it to a human-readable date/time STRING. you want [date_create_from_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) which takes in a time STRING, and gives you back a date/time object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use DateTime to convert an ISO date to a format you want:

```
$a = new \DateTime("2015-08-11T09:19:25Z");
$b = $a->format('H:i d.m.Y');
var_dump($b);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want use date function from PHP, you must set correct timezone:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
var_dump(date("H:i d.m.Y", strtotime('2015-08-11T09:19:25Z')));
```